# Is Security Update 2020-002 still available?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, upgrade, software-update

I downloaded Security Update 2020-002 a couple of days ago using `softwareupdate -d -a` from a terminal window.  Today I tried to install it but nothing happened.

```
$ softwareupdate -i -a --verbose
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
$
```

It does not show up in the `softwareupdate` history

```
$ softwareupdate --history | head
Display Name                                       Version    Date
------------                                       -------    ----
Safari                                             13.1       2020-04-05, 10:26:52
Security Update 2020-001                           10.13.6    2020-03-08, 22:14:32
Safari                                             13.0.5     2020-03-08, 22:14:32
```

Similarly, no pending updates are shown in the App Store:

[image: App Store Screenshot]

The Safari update that I downloaded along with this security update did successfully install in the App Store, without appearing to require any download time.

I'm running 10.13.6.

Has Security Update 2020-002 been disabled or cancelled?  I searched but didn't find anything indicating that it has been.  It still appears in the [list of available updates](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201222), for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Direct link: https://updates.cdn-apple.com/2020/macos/061-90747-20200319-5ded2636-188e-428b-90e6-2ed1507f6f46/SecUpd2020-002HighSierra.dmg

  in case it doesn't work, it's due to the key in between. Try the next link.
- Download page: https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos

Comment: That link works, thanks!  I guess my system got confused with having downloaded the update previously?  Weird.

Comment: Thanks!  Finally managed to get the 2GB download completed and was able to confirm that it works.